# Best practice for key with two values

Tags: java, apache-spark, dstream

So far I have a JavaDStream which first looked like this:

```
Value
---------------------
a,apple,spain
b,orange,italy
c,apple,italy
a,apple,italy
a,orange,greece
```

First i splitted up the rows and mapped it to a Key-Value pair in a JavaPairDStream:

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> pairDStream = inputStream.mapToPair(row -> {
    String[] cols = row.split(",");
    String key = cols[0];
    String value = cols[1] + "," + cols[2];

    return new Tuple2<String, String>(key, value);
});
```

So that i got this:

```
Key  | Value
---------------------
a    | apple,spain
b    | orange,italy
c    | apple,italy
a    | apple,italy
a    | orange,greece
```

In the end, the output should look like this

```
Key  | Fruit | Country
-------------------------------
a    | 2     | 3
b    | 1     | 1
c    | 1     | 1
```

which counts the number of unique fruits and countries of each key.

What is now the best practice? First, groupByKey/reduceByKey then split again? or is it possible to have two values for each key in a Key-Value pair like this?:

```
Key  | Value1 | Value2
----------------------
a    | apple  | spain
b    | orange | italy
c    | apple  | italy
a    | apple  | italy
a    | orange | greece
```

Comment: The second value can be Tuple as well: Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, String>>

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get distinct values with JavaPairDStream so you need to use its `.transformToPair(...)` method in order to convert it into JavaPairRDD first, then get distinct rows, then reduce by key and finally convert it back to JavaPairDStream

-use map to make JavaPairDStream for fruits: `<key, fruit>`, then apply  `.distinct( ).reduceByKey( )` inside `.transformToPair(...)` to get JavaPairDStream with `<key, distinct fruit count>`  (let's call it `<prds1>`)

-use map to make JavaPairDStream for countries: `<key, country>`, then apply  `.distinct( ).reduceByKey( )` inside `.transformToPair(...)` to get JavaPairDStream with `<key, distinct country count>`  (let's call it `<prds2>`)

-join both by key:  `<key, distinct fruit count, distinct country count>`:  (apply `prds1.join(prds2)`)

For future reference, in case if you wish to do the same but using Spark's Dataframe class:

-make a single dataframe out of given input data (assuming it has 3 columns referred as `<key, fruit, country>`  (call it 
`df`)

-select keys and fruits, apply distinct and then group by key: `df.select("key", "fruit").distinct( ).groupBy("key").sum("fruit")`  (call resulting dataframe `df1`)

-select keys and countries, apply distinct and then group by key: `df.select("key", "country").distinct( ).groupBy("key").sum("country")`  (call resulting dataframe `df2`)

-join df1 and df2 by key: `df1.join(df2, col("key").equalTo(col("key")), "inner")`